# Having whole page in SharePoint 2010 scroll (Including header and ribbon)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After downloading [this](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/), i noticed this works great, however I wanted to make the whole page the workspace/body and scroll including the header and the ribbon toolbar.  How is this done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, i fixed it here: http://myspexp.com/2010/06/14/expanding-the-scrollbar-past-the-ribbon-2/

Comment: Adding an external link and simply stating that it's fixed is not a proper answer, same applies. Consider adding a description of the solution and screenshots if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try removing the `id="s4-workspace"` from the div around your main content body in your master-page. This is the element that tells sharepoint to use all of it's ribbon resizing and scrolling logic. Without it the ribbon stays at the top of the page and you get one scrollbar across the entire page.